# Sails.js validation error on creating record: should be a number (instead of "xx", which is a string)

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to create a record in a table, it shares some attributes with other existing models.

```
// model:
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    ...
    contentType: 'string', // This is a combination foreign-key,
                           // which is not currently
    content: 'number',     // supported in waterline
    ...
  }
}

// creating code:
sails.log('item.content:', typeof item.content, item.content);
UserContentLibrary.create({
  user: prodSubscription.user,
  productContentSubscription: pcs.id,
  contentType: item.contentType,
  content: item.content,
}, function uclCreateCB(err, ucl){
  if (err){
    sails.log.error(err);
  }
  itemDone();
});

// error (console output):
debug: item.content: number 3
error: Error (E_VALIDATION) :: 1 attribute is invalid
... 
Invalid attributes sent to UserContentLibrary:
  content
    `undefined` should be a number (instead of "30", which is a string)
```

As you can see from the debug logging, the item.content is indeed a number, however for some reason it is converted to string somewhere, perhaps the adapter. How can I get around this?

Comment: what if you do `parseInt(content)` first?

Comment: do you have any callbacks running? Cause its not just making it a string, its making it 30 instead of 3. You may want to run node-debugger and find where the number changes.

Answer (score 13):

By changing the model attribute to `content: 'integer'` the issue is resolved. `integer` uses the `numeric` validator which accepts either a number OR a string containing only a number.